# Another pattern on Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help to write a regular expression to extract a value from a string.

input

```
EX000 YUUOO 23 $90SDFFSFF SFDFSFD SFDSFS RMK NDN 002  SFDSFDF SFD FSDF SFSF
```

I wanted to know how to look for `RMK NDN` ... and extract the value `002` (max of 4 digits)?

thanks

Comment: Here is a site with an applet that allows you to test java regex: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input will always look exactly like your example and only the digits `002` could vary as a sequence of three or four digits, this would work:

```
public static String getDigits(String input) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("RMK\\s+NDN\\s+(\\d{3,4})\\s+SFDSFDF");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  return (m.find()) ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
".*RMK NDN (\\d{1,4}).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for what you want and put the following digits into a capturing group

```
RMK\\sNDN\\s(\\d{1,4})\\s
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vfh4)